# 1004: Application-Defined or Object defined error after switching from Excel 2013/2016 to 2010

Tags: excel, vba

it's a very simple macro and I read tons of threads, none of which resolves my case. I get the .Caption line highlighted. I tried to Dim the form as new form and it does not help as well.I have a form which I want to call from a button which is apparently not done correctly from my side.

```
Sub BtnAdd_Click()
    frmAddCB.Caption = "Add Transaction"
    frmAddCB.Show
End Sub
```

Cheers,

Comment: Does it compile ? Did you check the References ?

Comment: Yes it compiles, and there are no references marked as (MISSING). I have Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Libary, OLE Automation,  Microsoft Office14.0 Object Libary, Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Libary. In my Excel 2016 I have exactly the same except it's 16.0 instead of 14.0.

Comment: Isn't the form the button's parent? `Me.Parent.Caption = "Add Transaction"` or `Me.Parent.frmAddCB.Caption = "Add Transaction"` What exactly is `frmAddCB`?

Comment: frmAddCB is the name of the form under Forms. I don't know how to make it a parent of my button. The code from my original post is in a Standard Module (Module 1). Perhaps this must be in the Form Module (right-click on the frmAddCB, View Code? The issue with this is that if I move the code to the form module, this macro does not show up in the list  when I right click on my button (shape) and Assign Macro.

Comment: Using a brand new form (UserForm1) does not have this issue.

Comment: Try adding `Load frmAddCB` as the first line of your macro then set the caption and show the form as you're doing now

Answer (score 0):

When executing this step by step with F8, just before the line that was highlighted on my standard module when executing with F5, it jumps to the Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() sub which is in the Form code itself. In that Initialize sub I had this line of code which was causing the error in Excel 2010:

```
TransTypeComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("TransType").RefersToRange))
```

After I changed this to the old-school way with a loop, it started working properly. Probably something about my dynamic range or something about the RefersToRange is not working the same way after Excel 2010.

```
For Each TT In Range("TransType")
    With Me.TransTypeComboBox
        .AddItem TT.Value
    End With
 Next TT
```